# CSS or jQuery not loading intermittently

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm testing a html file with a simple table with a large box or the html code that will be swapped out by the Ajax call. That code is a tabbed panel with a few images.

When I click on the anchor tags , it usually works fine , but sometimes the css link does not load and thus the box expands and the tabbed panel is just the html spread out in a mess.

Here's the test site: (http://www.mapartist.com/panels/b.html) Below is the simple code :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
     <link rel="Stylesheet" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.10/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
      <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.22/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</HEAD>     

<TABLE width= 800  height= 800 border=1>
  <TR>
    <TD width =600>
      <DIV id="spot"></DIV>
    </TD>
    <TD class="menu">
      <a href="a2Tabs.html"> Picture 1 </a> 
    </TD>
    <TD class="menu">
      <a href="a1Tabs.html"> Picture 2 </a> 
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>

<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" ">

   $(".menu a").click(function(){
     $("#spot").load(this.href);
     return false;
   })

</SCRIPT>

</HTML>
```

Comment: what is your problem ? i dont get it

Comment: The problem is intermittent. If you click on the anchor tags, the tabbed panel usually appears correctly. But every so often, it will load without the CSS or query and appear as straight HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the tabs init after the request :

```
$("#spot").load(this.href,function(){
    $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

And remove it from the other pages 'a1Tabs.html/a2Tabs.html', this way you make sure that the init will be fired only after the load of the tabs.

You could Try also the **Ivan Karaman's** suggested method `refresh` :

```
$("#tabs").tabs("refresh");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: $("#tabs").tabs( "refresh" ); https://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#method-refresh

Comment: @IvanKaraman thanks for your intervention, but every time the anchor is clicked new tabs are relacing the old ones in the page... added your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to page loading issue, after debugging your issue on the given link, it seems you are loading the css and js files from CDNs on every click. And sometime it does not load efficiently, thus issue arises.

I tried finding this with

```
load function()
```

of jquery and find that "Loading Page Fragments" concept can be used in your case to resolve the problem.